# Piping only works when running script directly (with shebang)?

Tags: python, pipe, fish

I wrote two Python scripts to experiment with how piping works with Python.

foo1.py:

```
#! /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3

import time

for i in range(10):
    print(i, flush=True)
    time.sleep(1)
```

foo2.py:

```
#! /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3

import time
import sys

print("2 start")

for l in sys.stdin:
    print(int(l)+100)
    time.sleep(0.05)
```

When I run these directly (`> ./foo1.py | ./foo2.py`), I get the expected output with 1 second delays between each number:

```
2 start
100
101
102
...
```

However, when I run these with Python (`python3 foo1.py | python3 foo2.py`), no output is generated (not even `2 start`) until after 10 seconds, when the entire output is printed at once. I am confused because it seems that these commands should be identical. Any insight on what the difference is here would be appreciated. I am running macOS 11.3.1 with Python 3.9.0.

Comment: What does `which python3` print?

Comment: What happens when you run `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3 foo1.py | /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3
 foo2.py`

Comment: `which python3` prints `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3`. But for some reason `Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3 foo1.py | /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3  foo2.py` also prints with delays

Comment: The alias was changing default line buffering? You can answer your own question here. Please provide details of what was going on.

Answer (score 2):

Update: I found the solution. A while ago I was having issues with python3 using a different version so I set up a Fish alias for python3:

```
function python3
    command python3.9 $argv
end
```

Deleting this alias fixed the issue. Further experimentation revealed that fish functions interfere with line buffering in an unexpected way.  Both `python foo1.py | ./foo2.py` and `./foo1.py | python foo2.py` produced the proper result. Additionally, when I redefined a function in the shell

```
function test_py
    command python3.9 $argv
end
```

then `test_py foo1.py | test_py foo2.py` worked perfectly. Only when the function was defined in a separate fish script (including `.config/fish/config.fish`) did the unexpected behavior emerge.